# Execute direct SQL

Tags: performance, sql, query, collection

I am working on a reports module and I've noticed that running direct SQL queries is quite faster than using Magento methods for retrieving a collection.

Is there any disadvantage to executing direct SQL queries?

Comment: The biggest problem is security. IF you know what you are doing all is fine. You know how to secure SQL queries?

Comment: I know how to secure SQL queries, thanks. I am worried that Magento may change the table structures in future versions.

Comment: This problem isn't solved by using explicit column names in collections too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it is not good practice, sometimes, you may need to execute direct SQL queries in Magento. However, be careful! The Magento model's are there for a reason and provide a layer of security which you will have to manually add to your own direct SQL queries. Using execute direct SQL queries, its architecture will be messed and be hard to develop any feature. It is better to learn Magento architecture more before developing, though it is tedious job!!